# Process data, calculate and create a new hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, ruby-2.0

I need to convert the `intermediate_hash` to `required_hash` given below.

**Reference Array**

```
ref_arr = [{"ver"=>"3.2", "start"=>"2014/2/12", "end"=>"2014/2/20", "id"=>"345"}, {"ver"=>"3.3", "start"=>"2014/3/19", "end"=>"2014/4/3", "id"=>"233"}]
```

**Intermediate Hash**

```
intermediate_hash = {
   "ver": {
      "abc-xxxx": {
         "'Process Start Date'":  "2014/1/10",
         "'Ready Start Date'": "2014/1/12",
         "'Product'": "Lumia-720",
       },
      "adc-xxxx": {
         "'Process Start Date'":  "2014/2/15",
         "'Ready Start Date'": "2014/2/17",
         "'Product'": "iphone5",
       },
      "efg-xxxx": {
         "'Process Start Date'":  "2013/12/10",
         "'Ready Start Date'": "2013/12/12",
         "'Product'": "htc",
       },
      "ghi-xxxx": {
         "'Process Start Date'":  "2013/10/3",
         "'Ready Start Date'": "2013/10/7",
         "'Product'": "iphone5",
       }, 
      "jkl-xxxx": {
         "'Process Start Date'":  "2013/10/23",
         "'Ready Start Date'": "2013/10/24",
         "'Product'": "Lumia-720",
       },
      "mno-xxxx": {
         "'Process Start Date'":  "2013/11/3",
         "'Ready Start Date'": "2013/11/4",
         "'Product'": "iphone5",
       },
    ...
   }
}
```

**Required Hash**

```
result = {
"3.2": {
    "lumia-720": {
        "'Before process QA'": 2
        "'After process'": 0,
    },
 　 "iphone5": {
        "'Before process QA'": 2,
        "'After process'": 1,
    },
    "htc": {
        "'Before process QA'": 1
        "'After process'": 0,
    }, 
  },
"3.3":..
}
```

**Rules for comparing**

**Before process:** reference_hash[:start]<=intermediate_hash[:process_start_date]

**After process:** reference_hash[:start]>intermediate_hash[:process_start_date]

My approach till now:

**First Step:** I tried to `group_by` by `product` by using this code.

```
hash = JSON.parse(File.read('details.json'))
summary = {}
hash.map do |x| 
 summary[x[0]] = {}
 summary[x[0]] = x[1].group_by{|x| x[1]['Product']}.each{|_, v| v.map!{|h| h[1]}}
end
```

So, i'm getting the final response as `grouped by` product. But i'm not able to understand how to effectively produce the `intermediate_hash` to `required_hash`.? As my attempt is going to multilevel iteration. Can someone please help me in this. ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to edit your question. Firstly, "Reference Hash" should be "Reference Array". That error is the first thing the reader sees, and it does not leave a good impression. Also, give this array a name, so all answers can merely reference it (e.g., `a = [{ver...`).  " Intermediate Hash" needs outer braces and a name (e.g., `h = {  ver:...`.  `{ "a": 1 }` is shorthand for `{ :"a"=>1 }`, not for  `{ "a"=>1 }`. I'm not sure if you are aware of that. I have not read the rest of your question closely, so other fixes may be required.

Comment: @cary: Sure, I agree with you. I'm editing it right now. thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the intermediate hash to the required hash, or are you asking how to go from the reference (array) to the required hash? What are you trying to accomplish with the code snippet you posted for your first step?

Comment: How to convert the intermediate hash to the required hash with the rules i have mentioned. With the code snippet, i tried to `group_by` by `product` as in the required hash.

Comment: Can you post the intermediate hash with actual sample data for "Process Start Date"s and "Ready Start Date"s?

Comment: I can fake the data. The actual data is private.

Comment: You want `intermediate_hash =`, not `intermediate_hash:`. Same for `result_hash =`, although there is no need to name the result, as answers will not reference it by name (i.e., `{"3.2": {...` is sufficient). I'm still mystified by your keys that are symbols such as `:"'Product'"`. I will delete this comment when you've seen it, so a reply is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I assume thats a typo in your `intermediate_hash` where you have `"Lumia-720"` instead of `"lumia-720"`? Also this isn't necessary but it may be more clear if you use `hash = JSON.parse(File.read('details.json'))` as it seems that you are implying that an array is being returned from that by using `arr`

Comment: i made the edits. Did u try any solution for it ?